# Exit a function in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm writing a web scraping project of extracting the username from Gmail account in R.
I have written a code where e is a list of the user name. function f contains code for scraping & for loop passes an index to function f, using index we will send user name to remote browser, then click next. If my username is right to control will go to the next page. If wrong I'll get a line saying *Error in username*. If my function finds the element for error in the username, then I want to exit function & go to for loop. How can I do it in R? Is there any other way to get my expected output?

Code-

```
e = list of Gmail username

f <- function(i){
 #Username
u <- remDr$findElement("css","value")
u$sendKeysToElement(list(e[i]))

 #click next
n <- remDr$fundElement("css","value")
n$sendKeysToElement(list("Enter"))

##if user name is wrong exit function & go to for loop
check <- tryCatch(remDr$findElemnt("css","value"), 
       error = function(e) print("error"))

if(typeof(check) =="S4"){
 ##what to do to exit function & go to for loop

 }else{
 print("continue")
}

for(i in sew(1,4))
 {
    f(i)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As @AncientSwordRage asked, I am moving my short reply from the *comment* section into the *answer* section.

Here is my original reply:

*To exit the function you can use return() function. You can place some arguments there if you would like your function to return a particular value.*

The `if` statement in your code then will look like:

```
if(typeof(check) =="S4"){
       return(NA)  # or some other value that would flag this condition
    
}else{
     print("continue")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either go the C route and return a value that signals particular type of condition. This approach is simple, but not very robust.

Usually, special values such as `NA`, `NaN` or `NULL` are returned, where a proper value is expected. You need to check then if the correct value was returned.

Note that functions, that do not have return value, return silently `NULL` instead, so you should be careful and design your program around that.

In case you need more complex signaling, you can use R's rich system of signals, including `stop()`, `warning()`, `message()` and many ways to work with them, from catching the warning using `try()` and `tryCatch()`, to restarting from error, or even developing your own type of conditions (unlikely to be required).

Usually, simple `stop()` statements are sufficient to fail hard and fail fast, with no recovery required.

A sample output for a more complex program loop might be:

```
run_me = function(){
  ...
  if(something_bad)
     stop("Something bad happened.")

  print("Never gone end here")
  }


run_me() # execution stops, print statement is never reached

save_me = function(){
  tryCatch(run_me(),
  error = recover()

  print("I will be printed!")
  }

save_me() # error is recovered and "I will be printed" is printed
```

See: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/conditions